# If I need to target Android API 18 and a method is deprecated in a later API version, how to proceed?

Tags: android, deprecated

I would like to use a [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)) that was introduced in Android API 18 but was deprecated in API 21. However, my app must be compatible with devices with API 18 installed.

Is the proper thing to do to simply continue using this deprecated method? Or should I check the version and have two versions of my code, one for API 18 and one for API 21 and later?

Comment: use different code for different versions

Comment: you answered yourself just check build version and use code accordingly. after deprecation it's usually in sdk or support lib for few more versions untill completely removed. it's better to add check today rather than fixing bug later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method that supports in API 18 and though it is deprecated it does not create you any problem. If you still want to put some validation around it then

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2&&android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

// write your code here which should work for version between 18 and 21.
}
else if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  { 
 // write the alternate code for API 21+
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're developing for less than Lolypop than you can use it , if you want the new androids use the replacement

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html

Answer (score 0):

From [Deprecated Annotation documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated.html)

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists.

No one says that will be removed but...imho is better to rewrite the code (if possible) and use the new backward compatibility method.

If you cannot do this check on SDK API version manually.